# Optimally restrict method call rate, the frequency a method can be called

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to restrict the frequency a method can be called. 
My purpose for this is to restrict the rate I process API callbacks.
*(Some API callbacks just won't stop when I want them to).*

I have a working solution, please provide a cleaner solution.

**Please provide a better solution.**

```
-(void)callbackRateLimited:(id)someDataProvided {

    static NSDate *date;
    static NSUInteger count;

    if (!date) {
        date = [NSDate new];
        count = 0;
    }

    double duration = fabs([date timeIntervalSinceNow]);
    NSLog(@"Duration :%f count:%lu",duration,count);

    if (count == 0) {

        NSLog(@"No waiting... processing API");

        [self processAPICallback];
        count++;
        return;
    }

    if (duration < 10.0f) { // 10 seconds
       NSLog(@"waiting.... too fast slow down");
       return;
    }

    NSLog(@"reset waiting state");
    //count = 0; not required here.
    date = nil; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following should work. This has the following caveats:

- You don't want to process ignored data after you have not received
  calls for a while.
- You want to limit the callback rate for all instances of the class together. If you want to limit it per object instance, then make
  `lastTime` a class variable instead of a static one.
- It have not tested it

.

```
- (void) callbackRateLimited:(id)someDataProvided
{
    static NSDate *lastTime = nil;
    if (!lastTime) {
        lastTime = [NSDate distantPast];
    }

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    if ([now timeIntervalSinceDate:lastTime] > 10) {
        lastTime = now;
        [self processAPICallback];
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you'll end up missing some changes, potentially.  You need something that says, "hey! a callback was squelched, if we didn't see a callback within N mess, then go ahead and fire one to pick up any changes that may not yet be processed".   That could be done in a number of ways, of which there'll be variable amounts of raciness.